# Query Builder SingleValuedAssociationField expected

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have native sql query with left join when have on with or condition, how to represent it in query builder ?

```
 $query = "  SELECT  te.id
            FROM    task_executions AS te
            INNER JOIN tasks AS t ON t.id = te.task_id
            LEFT JOIN cost_objects AS co ON co.id = t.cost_object_id
            LEFT JOIN cost_object_managers AS com ON com.cost_object_id = co.id OR com.cost_object_id = co.parent_id
```

and I need represent it in query builder but in `User` entity I have ManyToMany relation, without separate table and when I try left join with condition I have error `SingleValuedAssociationField expected.`

User entity

```
class User
{
...
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CostObject", mappedBy="users")
 */
private $costObjects;
}
```

CostObject entity

```
class CostObject
{
    /**
 * @var CostObject
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CostObject", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 * })
 */
private $parent;

    /**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="costObjects")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="cost_object_managers",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="cost_object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 * )
 */
private $users;
```

and my query builder without condition

```
        $qb->select('te')
        ->from('AppBundle:TaskExecution', 'te')
        ->innerJoin('te.task', 't')

        ->leftJoin('t.costObject', 'co')
        ->leftJoin('co.users', 'com')
```

this is `$query->getSQL()`

```
SELECT some_name FROM task_executions t0_ INNER JOIN tasks t1_ ON t0_.task_id = t1_.id LEFT JOIN cost_objects c2_ ON t1_.cost_object_id = c2_.id LEFT JOIN cost_object_managers c4_ ON c2_.id = c4_.cost_object_id LEFT JOIN users u3_ ON u3_.id = c4_.user_id ORDER BY t0_.execution_start DESC
```

and I need change it like in nativbe query but when I add condition to left join I get error

query with condition

```
        $qb->select('te')
        ->from('AppBundle:TaskExecution', 'te')
        ->innerJoin('te.task', 't')

        ->leftJoin('t.costObject', 'co')
        ->leftJoin(
            'co.users',
            'com',
            Join::WITH,
            $qb->expr()->orX
                (
                    'com.costObjects = co.id',
                    'com.costObjects = co.parent'
                )
            )
```

and error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 121 near 'costObjects =': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

I try add `IDENTITY` like reсomended me in answer

```
        ->leftJoin('t.costObject', 'co')
        ->leftJoin(
            'co.users',
            'com',
            Join::WITH,
            $qb->expr()->orX
                (
                    'IDENTITY(com.costObjects) = co.id',
                    'IDENTITY(com.costObjects) = co.parent'
                )
            )
```

but still have error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 130 near 'costObjects)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.
```

Comment: so .... your QB without condition did works? With condition didn't?

Comment: yes, but without condition part for join, my sql look like `LEFT JOIN cost_objects c2_ ON t1_.cost_object_id = c2_.id LEFT JOIN cost_object_managers c4_ ON c2_.id = c4_.cost_object_id LEFT JOIN users u3_ ON u3_.id = c4_.user_id ` But I need change it to `LEFT JOIN cost_object_managers AS com ON com.cost_object_id = co.id OR com.cost_object_id = co.parent_id`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$qb->select('te')
    ->from('AppBundle:TaskExecution', 'te')
    ->innerJoin('te.task', 't')

    ->leftJoin('t.costObject', 'co')
    ->leftJoin(
        'co.users',
        'com',
        Join::WITH,
        $qb->expr()->orX
            (
                'IDENTITY(com.costObjects) = co.id',
                'IDENTITY(com.costObjects) = co.parent'
            )
        )
```

Comment: still exception `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 130 near 'costObjects)': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.`

Comment: and `WITH` this is not the same `ON`. Because I got represent sql with additional condition, but need change `ON`  condition